# Joining two SQL tables with different column names in Metabase

Tags: sql, join, metabase

I am using [Metabase](http://www.metabase.com) to ask questions on my DB. I am trying to join two tables where the same info (user ID) has two different names. The code I wrote is as follows:

```
SELECT
    game_states.game_module AS game, count(*)
FROM
    game_states gs LEFT JOIN users u ON gs.user_id = u.id;
WHERE
    games_states.state = 'after_hands'
AND
    user.last_joined_stamp > now() - interval '30 days'
GROUP BY
    1
ORDER BY
    2 DESC
```

I keep getting the following error:
**ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "game_states" Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "gs". Position: 127**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you define a table alias, use it!

```
SELECT gs.game_module AS game, count(*)
-------^
FROM game_states gs LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON gs.user_id = u.id;
WHERE gs.state = 'after_hands' AND
------^
      u.last_joined_stamp > now() - interval '30 days'
------^
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Incidentally, you probably intend:

```
SELECT gs.game_module AS game, count(u.id)
FROM game_states gs LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON gs.user_id = u.id AND
        u.last_joined_stamp > now() - interval '30 days'
WHERE gs.state = 'after_hands' 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

You are using `LEFT JOIN`, so presumably want to include all matching games -- even those with no matching users.  If so, don't filter on `u` in the `where` clause and count the matches, so you can get `0`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just started to learn SQL and this is very helpful to me :)